# Hibernate Repository Query is invalid for MsSql Server

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

We are using MsSql Server in our Projekt.
Currently we use this docker image:
`mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-CU12-ubuntu`

Now I have a Problem with a generated Query.
The Repository Method looks like that:
`List<A> findByStatus(Status status);`

The (shortened) generated query:

```
select a0_.id as id1_60_,
       (SELECT count(a0_.id) from B b where b.aId = a0_.id AND b.status in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')) as formula4_
from dbo.A a0_
where a0_.status = ?;
```

The execution of this query fails:

```
Column 'dbo.A.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

I think this part is wrong: `... SELECT count(a0_.id) from B b ...`. The `a0_.id` is not part of B. 
It works if I manually change it to `b0_.id`.

My Spring configuration:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433"
    username: sa
    password: PW12345!
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
        default_schema: "dbo"
        format_sql: true
        show-sql: true

    hibernate:
      naming:
        physical-strategy: de.a.b.c.common.persistence.MyNamingStrategy
```

The strategy only formats all names uppercase.

```
    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        if (name == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Identifier(name.getText().toUpperCase(), name.isQuoted());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you the problem here. if you replace `count(a0_.id)` with `count(b.aid)` this will work.

Personally, however, I would rewrite your query using proper `JOIN` logic:

```
SELECT a0_.id AS id1_60_,
       COUNT(b.aId) AS formula4_
FROM dbo.A AS a0_ 
     LEFT JOIN B AS b ON b.aId = a0_.id
                  AND b.status IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
WHERE a0_.status = ?
GROUP BY a0_.id;
```

Comment: I don't write this query. It is generated via the Repository Method.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was a hard coded Formula in the entity. There I had to change `@Formula("(select count(id) ...` to `@Formula("(select count(b.id)...`